# Can/should one write a Comparator consistent with Object's equals method

Tags: java, equals, comparator

I have an object, `Foo` which inherits the default `equals` method from `Object`, and I don't want to override this because reference equality is the identity relation that I would like to use.

I now have a specific situation in which I would now like to compare these objects according to a specific field.  I'd like to write a comparator, `FooValueComparator`, to perform this comparison.  However, if my `FooValueComparator` returns 0 whenever two objects have the same value for this particular field, then it is incompatible with the equals method inherited from Object, along with all the problems that entails.

What I would like to do would be to have `FooValueComparator` compare the two objects first on their field value, and then on their references.  Is this possible?  What pitfalls might that entail (eg. memory locations being changed causing the relative order of `Foo` objects to change)?

The reason I would like my comparator to be compatible with equals is because I would like to have the option of applying it to `SortedSet` collections of `Foo` objects.  I don't want a `SortedSet` to reject a `Foo` that I try to add just because it already contains a different object having the same value.

Comment: If two Foo's are the same object (e.g., they have the same reference), then they cannot have different field values, right? Because they'd be the same object? Or are you talking about references of member variables?

Comment: It's difficult or impossible to "compare" reference locations.

Comment: @DavidKoelle You are certainly correct.  If `foo1 == foo2`, this implies that their field values will be equal and is therefore a more discriminating equivalence relation than any based on field values.  My issue is that it is strictly more discriminating.  Thus, there may be `Foo`s which have matching values but are not the same object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Hmm, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the documentation of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements `S` is said to be **consistent with equals** if and only if `c.compare(e1, e2)==0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` in `S`.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals.

It short, if the implementation of `Comparator` is not consistent with `equals` method, then you should know what you're doing and you're responsible of the side effects of this design, but it's not an imposition to make the implementation consistent to `Object#equals`. Still, take into account that it is preferable to do it in order to not cause confusion for future coders that will maintain the system. Similar concept applies when implementing `Comparable`.

An example of this in the JDK may be found in [`BigDecimal#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-), which explicitly states in javadoc that this method is not consistent with `BigDecimal#equals`.

---

If your intention is to use a `SortedSet<YourClass>` then probably you're using the wrong approach. I would recommend using a `SortedMap<TypeOfYourField, Collection<YourClass>>` (or `SortedMap<TypeOfYourField, YourClass>`, in case there are no *equals* elements for the same key) instead.  It may be more work to do, but it provides you more control of the data stored/retrieved in/from the structure.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi.  I should have been clearer about why I wanted to make my comparator consistent with my equals.  (I've updated by question to add this.)  I understand the possibility of using a comparator that is not consistent with equals, but ideally I would like to avoid the resulting effects of using such a comparator with a `SortedSet`.

Comment: The `SortedMap` suggestion is a good one.  Although it is somewhat cumbersome when expanded to handle multiple comparison on a number of fields, it does, as you said, offer more control.  Essentially, it separates control over the ordering of elements (according to the ordering of the keys) and inclusion of elements (according to the equals method used by the collections in the values of the map).  I have marked your answer as accepted.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dan you could also create a class `KeyForYourClass implements Comparable<KeyForYourClass>` that will contain the relevant fields for comparing/sorting your instances of `YourClass` rather than using a single field. And yes, it's more cumbersome but sadly that's the option in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You may have several comparators for a given class, i.e each per different field. 
In that case equals can not be reused. Therefore the answer is **not necessarily**. You should make them consistence however if your collection is stored in a sorted (map or tree) and the comperator is used to determined element position in that collection.

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for details.